# how to send dummy data on gpio pins of arduino uno.?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working with dht11 sensor and  arduino . I found the code from arduino site itself. Now I add few things like "

```
 if (temperature>70){
   //do something   
}
```

Now I want to test my code without sensor attached on gpio pins. How can I dump the dummy data ex. (0,50,70 Celcius)on the arduino pin through programming so that I can test the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `random()` function to generate the random values between a range.
Please refer https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Random for more details.

Since you are not connecting the sensor, you should not worry about the pin. Store the random value in a variable and check whether your code in the condition works. Once everything works as you expect, you can connect the sensor and the get the value from the sensor to the `temperature` variable.

```
long temperature;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // generate random number from 0 to 299
  temperature= random(300);

 if (temperature>70){
     Serial.println("Temperature is greater than 70"); 
 }
else {
     Serial.println("Temperature is less than or equal to 70"); 
}

  delay(50);
}
```

I've not tested this code in Arduino. But using the above method you should be able to simulate the values.